# Using jQuery, I can't seem to change the value of an input.... even in the console

Tags: jquery, business-catalyst

I'm using Adobe Business Catalyst and I'm trying to change the value of an input (in the admin area) using jQuery. When I use

```
 $('#inputID').val('blah')
```

it does not work. I also tried it in the console as well and nothing. I also tried targeting all text boxes and no values change.

```
$(':text').val('blah')
```

Why can't I change values programmatically? Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: Try `jQuery(':text').val('blah')`... Also try `jQuery == $` in console

Comment: What happens instead? Error messages?

Comment: check console and tell us what are errors , maybe there are some conflicts , use jQuery instead of $

Comment: Try `console.log($('#inputID').length)`

Comment: when using jQuery(':text').val('blah'); i get: [] as a result. When i use console.log($('#inputID').length) i get: 0 undefined. I inspected the element and that's the ID, it looks like they're .net generated, not too sure.

Comment: can you share the generated html sample

Comment: here's what that looks like: <input name="ctl00$cp$txtProductName" type="text" value="Beast" id="ctl00_cp_txtProductName" class="textbox415" onchange="sd();GenerateDefaultSlug(this.value)">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html is probably sitting inside of an iframe or frame OR you got the wrong ID.

Find the iframe, use contents(), grab the element.

Comment: how... $('#inputID').contents().val('foobar')?

Comment: No that is not the iframe you are looking for! `$("iframe")...`

Comment: there does seem to be an iframe... good call. how do i target the input in the iframe? $('iframe').contents('#inputID').val('foobar');?

Comment: `$('iframe').contents().find('#inputID').val('foobar');` or `$('iframe').find('#inputID').val('foobar');`